# Loop table from within mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL stored procedure which currently creates a table called 'prod_temp' and populates it with rows from a source table.

I would like the stored procedure to then loop through all the results of this 'prod_temp' table and update one of the columns - the value of which is the same as the value in the source table + 1. So far, I have the following.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProcedure;
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(IN s_region INT)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prod_temp;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE prod_temp SELECT * FROM prod WHERE FIND_IN_SET(s_region, regions);

        // select * from prod_temp
        // for each prod_temp row
            // select max(prod_id) from prod where ref = this row.ref
            // update this row, set prod_id = selected max(prod_id) + 1 
        // end loop 

    END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL MyProcedure(50);
```

Can somebody please fill in the blanks? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough detail for me can you supply sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop through the table, you can do it in one single update query:

```
UPDATE prod_temp AS p
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(prod) as max_prod_id, ref FROM prod GROUP BY ref) AS max_p
ON p.ref = max_p.ref
SET p.prod_id = max_p.max_prod_id + 1
```